# Cartesian product of two sets using BST in Haskell

Tags: haskell, set

I am using a Binary search tree to implement a set datatype in Haskell. I came across a problem, and tried it for really long, and gave up finally. Can you please help me out with the solution?

My Set datatype is implemented as follows:

```
 data Set a = Empty | Node a (Set a) (Set a) deriving(Show)
```

I wanted to make  the following functions:

```
 -- cartesian product of two sets
 cartesian :: Set a -> Set b -> Set (a, b)
 cartesian =   

 -- join two Sets together
 -- be careful not to introduce duplicates.
 union :: (Ord a) => Set a -> Set a -> Set a
 union =
```

I am aware of implementing these functions on a list, but not on a set, especially because I have implemented it in the form of a BST. That's the reason I am really confused on what my steps must be. I cannot change the set to a list, and then solve the function, as the ORD constraint is not defined in my type signature of the cartesian function.

My confusion in the union function was that, how do I avoid the duplicates without using the EQ constraint?

I cannot use the Data.Set module or any other prelude functions. I cannot change the type signature as well.

My setmap function:

```
 setmap :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> Set a -> Set b
 setmap f Empty = Empty
 setmap f (Node val l r) = Node (f val) (setmap f l) (setmap f r)
```

My setfoldr function:

```
 setfoldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> Set a -> b -> b
 setfoldr f Empty acc = acc 
 setfoldr f (Node val l r) acc = setfoldr f (f val (setfoldr f r 
 acc)) l
```

My setfoldr function is giving an error; if you could help me out with this as well . thanks

Thanks in advance,

Comment: have you seen [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

To implement the Cartesian product, you don't need to compare the elements. The trees have already been built in order. For any value `a` anywhere in the first tree `tree1`, you can build a tree `treeMap (a ,) tree2` which will maintain the second tree's order, since all the first entries in the tuples are the same. Then you can just replace that `a` with this new tree, and the new combined tree -- which will be the Cartesian product of the two -- will also be in order, the *lexicographical* order.

This indeed assumes there are no duplicates in the first tree.

So, implementing `treeMap :: (b -> c) -> Set b -> Set c` is easy (treating is as a tree, not even a BST nor as a Set, as @amalloy mentions in the comments; just a structural mapping function), and you'll end up with the `Set (Set (a,b))` tree. Now, smashing this back into `Set (a,b)` is also easy, since the `(a,b)` values are already ordered, by construction. So after enumeration you'll get an ordered nested list, which you can then concatenate, and fold the resulting list back into the valid search tree without ever needing to compare the tuples, just doing it positionally.

Assuming you've implemented `treeFoldr` and `treeMap` with expected semantics, this could be coded as

```
setCrossProd :: Set a -> Set b -> Set (a,b)
setCrossProd s1 s2 = fromAscendingList abs
  where
  abs = concatMap toList nested  -- abs :: [(a,b)]
  nested = toList crossed   -- nested :: [Set (a,b)]
  -- toList :: Set a -> [a]
  toList t = treeFoldr (:) [] t
  crossed = mapTree       -- crossed :: Set (Set (a,b))
              (\a -> mapTree (\b -> (a,b)) s2)
              s1
  -- fromAscendingList :: [a] -> Set a
  fromAscendingList xs = ......
```

(or something like that; not tested). The point of having `fromAscendingList :: [a] -> Set a` is that the list is already known / assumed to be sorted, so we won't perform any comparisons: we *know* / assume that any element that comes later is bigger than the one before it, positionally, in the list. It has no constraint in its type, as it won't perform any `insert`s; it will construct the trees structurally right away.

About your `setfoldr` function, you just need to move `l` to be the 2nd parameter, not 3rd, in the second equation:

```
setfoldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> Set a -> b -> b
setfoldr f Empty acc = acc 
setfoldr f (Node val l r) acc =      -- f   ::     a -> b -> b
  setfoldr f l                       -- l   :: Set a
             (f val                  -- val ::     a
                (setfoldr f r        -- r   :: Set a
                            acc))    -- acc ::          b
```

Just like `r` is in the 2nd position, so must be `l`. This is also seen in `setfoldr`'s type. *Follow the types.*

---

As to the issue of implementing the union, you already have the `Eq` constraint when you have `Ord`, because `Eq` is a superclass of `Ord`:

```
> :i Ord
class Eq a => Ord a where
  compare :: a -> a -> Ordering
  .......
```

any `Ord` type must also be an `Eq` type.

Comment: I am sorry but I am a beginner in haskell . I didn't really understand anything what you just said in the second paragraph.  I already had created my own functions called setmap, and setfoldr. Could you maybe just simplify what you told or share a few lines of the cartesian function code. Also about the union function,what do I do when I encounter a duplicate ?

Comment: re the duplicates, you can call `a==b` with the two values `a` and `b` to detect this. `==` is defined, since you have `Ord` constraint, and it implies `Eq` constraint. you can just use `==` to detect duplicates, and in such case not insert any new values into the tree that already contains one such equal value.

Comment: re setmap, do include it into your question -- click on "Edit" under it and add that code. it looks most likely that it is that function which I called `fmap`. the `(a,)` thing is a function: it can also be written `(\b -> (a , b))`. (that construct `(a ,)` is known as "operator section", you can look it up for further info). so please edit your question, add your `setmap` into it. you will also need a function `toList`, and `fromAscendingList`. include any that you already have, like `setfoldr`, so I have something to build on.

Comment: for instance, if it's a good `setfoldr` implementation, I could show you how to implement `toList` function with it. well, usually, it's `foldr (:) [] yourObject`. but I'd have to see your implementation to be certain.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a great idea to implement `fmap` for this type. If `f x` sorts differently from `x` you will have a tree, but not a BST.

Comment: @amalloy makes sense, thanks. so we'll just call it "setmap" -- OP mentions this above. or maybe call it `treeMap`, actually -- I mean the simple (is it "natural"?) structural map, which might even introduce duplicates in the result, so certainly could produce a non-set.

Comment: I have edited my question. I have used toList, fromList, and insert function. I have used fromList by inserting the elements repeatedly in the set. The definition is fromList  Ord a => [a] -> Set a, insert :: Ord a => a -> Set a -> Set a , toList :: Set a -> [a]. Could you please help me out with my setfoldr function as well. I just tested it now, and it gives me an error.

Comment: the only thing left is to implement `fromAscendingList`. try to do it, and if you have difficulties, please post a new question with all the relevant code (so ppl won't dv you :) ).

Comment: so you have implemented the fromAscending function by now. you can now test this one as well. I've just tested it, `toList $ setCrossProd (frmAsclst [1..3]) (frmAsclst [10,20])` produces `[(1,10),(1,20),(2,10),(2,20),(3,10),(3,20)]`.  so it works! :)