# How to use tow filters in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, filter

I want to write a function that prints all the subsequences that are sorted and another condition.

I already implemented a function that shows all the sorted subsequences as this:

```
allSubseqs:: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
allSubseqs =  filter' isSorted . subsequences
```

I want to do further filters to select only the list with the maximum length.
I know how to do it with let, but I want to add it to allSubseqs function directly:

This is the results of the code and it is correct:

```
[[3,5,7,8],[1,5,7,8],[1,2,7,8]]
```

Comment: You could use one of: 1) `maximumOn` (the easiest), 2) `maximumBy`, 3) `foldl1'`, 4) explicit recursion (if you can't or don't want to use libraries).

Comment: How would you do it with `let`? (If you mean your second code snippet, I don't see that snippet doing anything with lengths; what's up with that?)

Comment: @chi  maximumOn and maximumBy will show only one list, while I want all the lists with the maximum length

Comment: @DanielWagner see the results of the code, I add it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to make your function point-free.  That is, you want to define all of your filters and list manipulations as a sequence of function applications rather than with variable and let bindings.  That's certainly doable!

One nice way to go about this that I like is to use the arrow combinators rather than `(.)`, as it allows one to define a left-to-right *pipeline* of functions rather than the typical (mathematical) right-to-left composition.  We'll start with the import:

```hs
import Control.Arrow ((>>>), (&&&))
```

The `>>>` operator is just flipped composition, and we'll come back to `&&&` in a bit.

Now, let's take your `allSubseqs` function and write it in this arrow style:

```hs
allSubseqs:: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
allSubseqs = subsequences >>> filter' isSorted
```

Next, we want to do another filter, this time on the length of the list, but we also need to know the maximum length of the list.  Typically, this is where one would use a let statement or variable binding (as you did), but instead, we can use `&&&`.  The `&&&` combinator takes two functions, each of which takes the same input, and produces a pair of the outputs of the functions.  We can use it in place of the `let` like so:

```hs
allSubseqsAndLongestLength :: Ord a => [a] -> (Int, [[a]])
allSubseqsAndLongestLength = subsequences 
    >>> filter' isSorted 
    >>> (maximum . map' length) &&& id
```

The output so far is now a pair of the maximum length of a sorted subsequence along with the list of all sorted subsequences.  It's time to pipe this into the final filter:

```hs
allLongestSubseqs :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
allLongestSubseqs = subsequences 
    >>> filter' isSorted 
    >>> (maximum . map' length) &&& id
    >>> uncurry (filter' . (. length) . (==))
```

We could have written that last line as `>>> (\(maxLen, lst) -> filter' ((== maxLen) . length) lst)`, but I took the liberty of making it point-free like the rest of the function.

There you have it!  You can even add more `filter`s or other list manipulations as you want by simply composing them onto the end of the chain.

Answer (score 2):

Well, one of the `let`s can go straight off; your `let x2 = x1` isn't really doing much, and we can just replace `x2` with `x1` everywhere.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let x1 = allSubseqs2 [6,3,1,5,2,7,8,1]
  print $ filter' ((==) (maximum (map' length x1)) . length) x1
```

Technically, we could also replace all occurrences of `x1` with `allSubseqs2 [...]`, but that would, unfortunately, compute the subsequences twice. So that `let` must stay.

Still, we can factor out the call to `allSubseqs2` and `filter'`, combining them in a single function, if that's desired. It looks almost identical, just replacing `print` with... nothing!

```
longSubseqs values = do
  let x1 = allSubseqs2 values
  filter' ((==) (maximum (map' length x1)) . length) x1
```

Actually, this is a bit deceptive; most Haskellers will expect there to be something monadic going on when they see a `do` block, and there isn't any such thing going on here. Let's just change that `do`/`let` to a `let`/`in`:

```
longSubseqs values = let x1 = allSubseqs2 values in
  filter' ((==) (maximum (map' length x1)) . length) x1
```

Using either definition, we can now write a shorter `main`:

```
main = print $ longSubseqs [6,3,1,5,2,7,8,1]
-- OR
main = do
  print $ longSubseqs [6,3,1,5,2,7,8,1]
```

Comment: Might be better to recompute subsequences than to save them, keeping a bunch of lists in memory ain't exactly cheap

Comment: @DanielWagner So you think it is impossible to add the filter conditions to allSubseqs function without adding another function like in your example longSubseqs?

Comment: @RJ94 No, of course that's possible. You can divvy up code pretty much however you want.

Comment: @DanielWagner yes my question was how to modify allSubseqs function to take the lists with the maximum elements? without doing that in the main or any other function

Comment: like for example add that filter before ( filter' isSorted . subsequences ), I don't know how to add two filters to the same function.

Comment: Yes, you explained the idea very well, but with let, I can't add a composition function before (filter' isSorted . subsequences) with using let. So let is required in this case.

Comment: @RJ94 "How to modify `allSubseqs` function to take the lists without doing that in any other function?" You just... do it. For example, one way would be to start from the definition of `longSubseqs` given here and inline the definition of `allSubseqs2`.

Comment: @DanielWagner yes it is too clear but even though I need "let" , can I do it for example by writing :  filter' (condition to select the maximum elemnts) .  filter' isSorted . subsequences

Comment: @RJ94 No, no solution exists of exactly that form. However, `(\xs -> filter' condition xs) . filter' isSorted . subsequences` is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Using the "decorate-process-undecorate" paradigm  a.k.a. [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) as in [DDub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14802384/ddub)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71880440/849891) lets you have the additional filter in the chain, after preparing the data for it to work on.

But it could be better to avoid that second filter entirely here, by generating the sublists in order in the first place, *longest first*, then just taking the head element:

```
longestSorted :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
longestSorted = rpowers >>>
   map (filter isSorted) >>>
   dropWhile null >>>
   concat . take 1

-- > longestSorted [1,4,3,5]
-- [[1,4,5],[1,3,5]]
```

This uses `rpowers` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70630704/849891):

```
-- longest first:
rpowers :: [a] -> [ [[a]]]
rpowers []     =  [ [[]] ]
rpowers (x:xs) = 
     [ map (x:) b ++ a |  (a:b:_) <- tails ([[]] ++ rpowers xs) ] 
      ++          [ [[]] ] 

-- shortest first, for comparison:
powers :: [a] -> [ [[a]]]
powers []     =  [ [[]] ]
powers (x:xs) =  [ [[]] ] ++
     [ map (x:) a ++ b |  (a:b:_) <- tails (powers xs ++ [[]]) ]
```